# Compare dates in scala present in dataframe column

Tags: scala, apache-spark, apache-spark-sql

I am trying to compare dates below in filter as below:-

dataframe `KIN_PRC_FILE` has column `pos_price_expiration_dt` that has value `9999-12-31`

```
val formatter = new SimpleDateFormat("yyyy-MM-dd");
val CURRENT_DATE = formatter.format(Calendar.getInstance().getTime());

val FILT_KMART_KIN_DATA= KIN_PRC_FILE.filter(s"(pos_price_expiration_dt)>=$CURRENT_DATE AND pos_price_type_cd").show(10)
```

but seems above query returns null records, can somebody help me to understand what is wrong here.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You just need to add single commas to your current_date variable

```
KIN_PRC_FILE.filter(s"pos_price_expiration_dt >= '$CURRENT_DATE'")
```

**Quick example here**

**INPUT**

```
df.show
+-----------------------+---+
|pos_price_expiration_dt| id|
+-----------------------+---+
|             2018-11-20|  a|
|             2018-12-28|  b|
|                   null|  c|
+-----------------------+---+
```

**OUTPUT**

```
df.filter(s"pos_price_expiration_dt>='$CURRENT_DATE'").show

+-----------------------+---+
|pos_price_expiration_dt| id|
+-----------------------+---+
|             2018-12-28|  b|
+-----------------------+---+
```

Answer (score 0):

Note that you are using string comparison that has date values. Since you have it in the descending order i.e yyyy-MM-dd, this works, but not safe always.

You should consider casting the column to "date" format before doing such comparisons.
And for the current date you can always use the built-in variable. Check this out:

```
scala> val KIN_PRC_FILE = Seq(("2018-11-01"),("2018-11-15"),("2018-11-30"),("2018-11-28"),(null)).toDF("pos_price_expiration_dt").withColumn("pos_price_expiration_dt",'pos_price_expiration_dt.cast("date"))
KIN_PRC_FILE: org.apache.spark.sql.DataFrame = [pos_price_expiration_dt: date]

scala> KIN_PRC_FILE.printSchema
root
 |-- pos_price_expiration_dt: date (nullable = true)


scala> KIN_PRC_FILE.show
+-----------------------+
|pos_price_expiration_dt|
+-----------------------+
|             2018-11-01|
|             2018-11-15|
|             2018-11-30|
|             2018-11-28|
|                   null|
+-----------------------+


scala> KIN_PRC_FILE.filter(s"pos_price_expiration_dt >= current_date ").show
+-----------------------+
|pos_price_expiration_dt|
+-----------------------+
|             2018-11-30|
|             2018-11-28|
+-----------------------+


scala>
```